# My invite email to a SE site in private beta never arrived. Can another be sent upon request?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

The new SE site in question is [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2f) fresh out of Area51. I've been following and committed to this since its inception. When it went into private beta phase however, I never got the invitation email because I hit my limit in spamgourmet.

I've increased the limit since then but I cannot get back any deleted emails of the past. How can I request for another invitation email so I can participate in the private beta?

Comment: Well, posting here should certainly work :P

Comment: @cpast I would hope so :p Still, I'm holding out for a more automated method. eg. Some option to resend in your profile or something to that effect.